Pandemic move to another state due to salary reduction
During the pandemic, many employees were let go or furloughed . I was kept on but my salary was reduced. Due to this, I could not keep my house and had to find another place for my family to live. The agency is in Manhattan and I found rent I could afford in Florida. I found a house to rent for $1,600 for my 2 kids, my husband and my elderly mother. The job agreed as they reduced my salary and they know I had no choice. The umbrella agency is moving things around and I want to know what my rights are in case this gets close to my position. They do not have a place where I am where I can work in an office. I have an Autistic son who currently goes to a private school and I must be available to take care of him. What are my rights in this situation? I will have been at this agency for 26 years in August. Thanks!

Can you describe this agency a bit more ? Are they a real company that hires and pays employees directly ? Or are they a middle man (a third party agency) who hires employees for other cooperations ?

I am so sorry to hear about your situation, and I wish you and your family the best. But, can you please clarify what would you like to know more about your rights regarding which ones of the followings : The right to have higher salary or to have the same salary as your old salary before the pandemic ? The right to have job safety ? The right to work in certain states or certain city with lower rent ? The right to work from home or to have more flexible time to take care your son ?

Ultimately, both New York and Florida are states with at-will employment.  Outside of being terminated for being a whistleblower, or for being a member of a protected class (race, age, religion, etc.) you can be let go at any time without any reason.
What you can do:

Keep your resume updated
Keep some money in the bank!!!
Make sure your skills are current for what's in demand in the job market.


Unfortunately, having a son who is in a protected class does not put you in a protected class. You have no special legal protection here.
